# What is the relationship between derivation and derivation trees?

Tags: context-free-grammar, automata, automata-theory

It was written in ullmans book but i did not under stand well how it works. Can anybody explain even in simple context? I'd be really glad.

Comment: Can you include more detail, for instance giving an example of a derivation and a derivation tree? Are you referring to finite automata (as you've tagged this) or context free languages?

Comment: sorry about that it's a part of my subject (automata). Im new to the tags, simply put talking about context free language/grammar. Is there a difference between the two?

Comment: SO seems to use finite-automata specifically for regular languages, so I've updated the tag here.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3250/proof-of-equivalence-of-parse-trees-and-derivations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A derivation is some sequence that starts with the start symbol S, ends with a string in the language, and the intermediate steps may contain terminals and nonterminals. Each step in the sequence expands one nonterminal using a production rule.

A parse tree is rooted at the start symbol, has terminal symbols as leaves, and the children of a node correspond to a production rule.

For instance, with the grammar `S -> a | 1 | S + S`, a derivation for `a + a + 1` might be

```
S -> S + S -> a + S -> a + S + S -> a + S + 1 -> a + a + 1
```

and the corresponding parse tree might be

```
   S
 / | \
S  +  S
|    /|\
a   S + S
    |   |
    a   1
```

Some questions to ask at this point are: For a given language or grammar, does a particular string have only one parse tree? Only one derivation? For a particular derivation, is there a unique parse tree, or vice versa?

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped me alot! I tried rereading the book and i guess i've misunderstood some stuff. But this gave me a simple idea of how it works now, again thankyou so much :)